# Firefox Not Responding to .addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

There's a couple things I'm trying to make happen with a sticky nav on a website. I have it working in all browsers, except Firefox.

1. I want the links to change as the window scrolls.
2. I want to add a class to change the navigation at a certain point.

Here's the code that's been working in Chrome:

```
<section id="nav">
<nav>
<ul>
    <li id="p1"><a href="#b" id="nb" class="pill">Snap</a></li>
    <li id="p2"><a href="#c" id="nc" class="pill">Organize</a></li>
    <li id="p3"><a href="#d" id="nd" class="pill">Store</a></li>
    <li id="p4"><a href="#e" id="ne" class="pill">Unify</a></li>
    <li id="p5"><a href="#f" id="nf" class="pill">Share</a></li>
    <li id="n-play" class="sticky-dl"><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.trunx">Get it on Google Play</a></li>
    <li id="n-app" class="sticky-dl"><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/app/id739060178?mt=8">Download on the App Store</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</section>
```

The Javascript/jQuery

```
// Auto Nav Active Switching
var nav = $('#nav-sticky-wrapper').height();
var navh = nav+1;
var b = $('section#b').offset().top - navh;
var c = $('section#c').offset().top - navh;
var d = $('section#d').offset().top - navh;
var e = $('section#e').offset().top - navh;
var f = $('section#f').offset().top - navh;
var remove = $('nav ul li a');

setInterval(function() {
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() < b ) {
        $('section#nav ul').removeClass('stuck');
        $('section#nav ul li.sticky-dl').fadeOut(250);
    } else {
        $('section#nav ul').addClass('stuck');
        $('section#nav ul li.sticky-dl').fadeIn(250);
    }

    if ( $(window).scrollTop() < c ) {
        $(remove).removeClass('active');
        $('#nb').addClass('active');
    } else if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= c && $(window).scrollTop() < d ) {
        $(remove).removeClass('active');
        $('#nc').addClass('active');
    } else if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= d && $(window).scrollTop() < e ) {
        $(remove).removeClass('active');
        $('#nd').addClass('active');
        //bonusoff();
    } else if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= e && $(window).scrollTop() < f ) {
        $(remove).removeClass('active');
        $('#ne').addClass('active');
        // Runs Bonus Animation upon Entry
        bonus();
    } else if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= f ) {
        $(remove).removeClass('active');
        $('#nf').addClass('active');
    }




});
```

Does Firefox not respond to setInterval or something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: `setInterval` requires a ** delay time** to wait. What is the delay you want? ex: `setInterval(function(){...}, 3000);`

Comment: @SimchaKhabinsky Thanks a ton! That fixed the problem right away. I wish I had enough rep to upvote your answer. Thanks for the awesome answer. :)

Comment: You can still set my answer is "The Answer" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` requires a ** delay time** to wait. What is the delay you want? ex: `setInterval(function(){...}, 3000);`